# How to show Different pages on different click in tab bar in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am implementing tab bar using jquery mobile.I need to show different pages on different buttons on tab bar .But it is showing in same page.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/654gX/

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1" onclick="ShowHide(this)">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2" onclick="ShowHide(this)">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3" onclick="ShowHide(this)">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="content" class="content">
   <div id="tab-1">
      <h2>Here is the first tab</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="tab-2">
      <h2>Here is the second tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
       <h2>Here is the third tab</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code isn't correct. Where are different pages? First you need to create pages, then you can change the page.

Comment: can tou please give me any example..?

Comment: My updated http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/654gX/1/ it is also not working..:( i need button on first tab on second i need list view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure you app, first follow this structure given at [jquery mobile docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/#PagesDialogs).
Secondly navbars are supposed to be inside footer or header, so wrap you navbar around footer then you need fixed header and footer with same data-id so the pages transition between dynamically keeping the same header and footer, which looks like tabs, example

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="sameheader">
        <h1>Single page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build your first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>      

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-id="samefooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->.
<div data-role="page" id="two">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="sameheader">
        <h1>Single page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Different page same footer.</p>      

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="samefooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page2 -->
```

[Js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jpq5q/)

Comment: Thanks very thing is fine .But if i need tab bar on header below (Top) header is it possible? to add sub header with tab bar?

Comment: I add "header" instead of "footer" it is showing but it is showing above the main header

Comment: just move the navbar div from footer div to header div,

Comment: I do this but there is fluctuation  in data while going to second page

Comment: by fluctuation you mean the data changes, or the data on page two slides up a bit first time you switch to it ?

Comment: yes ..second one  the data on page two slides up a bit first time you switch to it

Comment: I think that is because the navbar was designed to be on the footer, but anyway you can maybe add some padding on it